# Accessing local database using Heroku

Tags: node.js, oracle, express, heroku, https

So I've developed a Node.js app that accesses an Oracle database (that can be accesssed by all connected clients) for connected users, and sends them push notifications depending on certain query results. I used the web-push API (details at https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push) to send push notifications to the connected clients, who essentially send a subscription with an endpoint to the server, and receive notifications based off this data.
1) I can't seem to host this app over simple LAN using my IP address since it doesn't have SSL certificate (https extension) and service workers don't work. 
2) I deployed the app using Heroku, and now can send push notifications to various clients, but am unable to access the database (throws me an error).

How do I connect to the oracle database when deployed on Heroku? Is there a workaround?

I use the following simple code to connect to my database:

`connection = await oracledb.getConnection(  {`
      `user          : <username>,`
      `password      : <password>,`
      `connectString : <connectionString>`
    `});`

Comment: For many reasons, if you're going to host the application publicly you shouldn't have it connect to a local database. Hosting your database in the cloud is probably the best option.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use service like *ngrok* which allows to access local port publicly.

The process of how to setup ngrok can be found in the link below
https://ngrok.com/docs

For example if I was running PostgreSQL server on my local machine and  I want to expose that  PostgreSQL server listening on the default port, I will run below command with ngrok

`ngrok tcp 5432`

And the tcp url & port that will be displayed after port is exposed successfully will be database host name & port respectively.

Comment: This isn't a production-friendly solution.

Comment: Yes, totally agree with you.

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use oracle cloud services..ATP database is an always free feature..